# Probability of Wiener process infimum

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

$(W_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ a standard Wiener process. I would like to calculate $\mathbb{P}\left(\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}W_t>0\right)$, but I'm stuck :( Can anyone help, please?

Comment: hello, please can you add what you have tried and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\{\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}W_t>0 \} &= \{W_{\frac{1}{2}}+\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}(W_t-W_{\frac{1}{2}})>0 \} \\
&= \{W_{\frac{1}{2}}+\inf_{t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(Z_t)>0 \} \\
&= \{W_{\frac{1}{2}}+\sup_{t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(-Z_t)>0 \} \\
&= \{W_{\frac{1}{2}}-\sup_{t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(B_t)>0 \} \tag{1}
\end{align}

where $Z_t$ and $B_t$ are two brownian motions independant to $W_t$ and $B_t = -Z_t$.

We know also the [law of supremum of BM](https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/supremum-of-brownian-motion/), then
$$\sup_{t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(B_t) \stackrel{d}=|B_{\frac{1}{2}}|$$
Then, from $(1)$ we have
$$\{\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}W_t>0 \} = \{W_{\frac{1}{2}}-|B_{\frac{1}{2}}|>0 \} = \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(X-|Y|\right)>0 \}=\{X-|Y|>0 \} $$
with $X,Y$ are independent and follow the standard normal distribution.

So,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}W_t>0\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X-|Y|>0\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(\{ X>Y\}\cap \{Y>0 \}\right) +\mathbb{P}\left(\{ X>-Y\}\cap \{Y<0 \}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X>Y>0\right) +\mathbb{P}\left(-X<Y<0\right) \\
\end{align}
As $X,Y \stackrel{d}= \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then the two probabilities are both $\frac{1}{8}$ the plan $Oxy$. Hence

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\inf_{t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]}W_t>0\right) = \frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{4} $$